# Do masses have to be identical in elastic collisions?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

Is it necessary that masses of two colliding objects be equal, for them to conserve kinetic energy (along with momentum)? I ask this question because I have seen a scenario where the equation implying the conservation of kinetic energy and conservation of momentum has been derived keeping in mind objects of equal mass.

Comment: A tennisball dropped on a trampoline. Elastic.

Comment: -1. What makes you think this is the case?

Comment: Elastic scattering of electrons off protons: $e^- p \rightarrow e^- p$, is exceptionally elastic (with different masses).  An example of an inelastic scattering: the proton is excited into a baryon resonance, say a $\Delta^+$, which effectively absorbs energy from the electron, reconfiguring the proton's quarks.

Comment: see this  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/elacol.html

Comment: @sammygerbil I thought that this is the case as a Physics book had come to the conclusion 'relative speed of approach = relative speed of separation, in an elastic collision' by demonstrating a scenario where equal masses have been used. However, I have now understood the concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Elastic" simply means that no energy is dissipated during the collision, so the total kinetic energy before and after the collision is the same.

There is no reason why the masses should be the same. If you consider the collision of two unequal masses in the center-of-mass (c.o.m.) frame (which always makes collision problems easier), then in that frame the initial and final velocities of the two masses will be the same; if we denote the "velocity before collision" = $v_1$ and after = $v_1'$, we can write

$$ m_1 v_1 + m_2 v_2 = m_1 v_1' + m_2 v_2' = 0$$

(for conservation of momentum), and

$$\frac12 m_1 v_1^2 + \frac12 m_2 v_2^2 = \frac12 m_1 v_1'^2 + \frac12 m_2 v_2'^2$$

It is easy to see both these will be true when $v_1 = -v_1'$ and $v_2 = -v_2'$, regardless of the masses $m_1$ and $m_2$.

Adding a velocity of the center of mass to the above equations complicates them, but doesn't change the underlying physics.

Answer (score 1):

The masses do not have to be identical for an elastic collision.

Comment: So could you kindly demonstrate an example where two non-identical masses collide, and the initial and final kinetic energy still remain the same?

Comment: @Coder511 Bouncy ball bouncing off the ground

Comment: @Coder511 Any real life example is flawed as no collision is the ideal elastic collision, even if masses are identical. However any nearly full elastic collision can happen between objects of different masses, hence balls bouncing back from the ground which involves the mass of the ball and the mass of the Earth, which is usually a difference of more than 1 : 10E24.

Comment: @Coder511 - That's not an elastic collision (and it doesn't conserve momentum, either). An elastic collision would have the first trolley moving to the right at 5/3 m/s and the second moving to the left at 10/3 m/s. Total post-collision momentum is 5 kg*m/s, total post-collision kinetic energy is 12.5 J.

Comment: @DavidHammen Yes, you are completely correct; it appears I had made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

An elastic collision is a **condition** imposed in the system. It is an asumption you make in the system.

It is analogous to saying that you have a ball rolling without slipping; it is just an ideal situation you want to consider. It does not mean that a ball **can not** slip in order to roll.

This means that you can consider elastic collision between any two masses, it is only an assumption you are making of the situation.